# Android DownloadManager remove() API

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

When i want to cancel the pending and ongoing downloads handled by the DownloadManager, i use the [remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove(long...)) API. It works great. But it seems that remove() call returns **almost immediately** but the default system notification indicating the download status continues to show for quite some time. Is there a callback API that gets called when the system notification actually gets dismissed? Or in other words, is there a "synchronous" equivalent of remove() API? I can achieve what i need by handling it in my code exclusively. But before i delve into that option, just wanted to see if there is a more painless way to achieve my desire.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DownloadManager sends an IPC to another process which does the actual downloading.  So no, there's no synchronous method of doing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269217/android-downloadmanager-remove-how-to-determine-when-the-remove-operation